# Primeng how to make sure dropdown formControlName is assigned after options was loaded

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I have primeng dropdown `p-drowdown` and fetching options value from database. But the problem is
dropdown value `formControlName="fromWarehouseId"` is assigned **before** `[options]="fromWarehouseList"` is assigned. For example ;

```
 <p-dropdown
     #fromWareHouse
      [options]="fromWarehouseList"
      class="w-100"
      formControlName="fromWarehouseId"
      placeholder="{{ 'form.btn.select' | translate }}"
    >
 </p-dropdown>
```

I have this dropdown in my component template. When the page is loaded `fromWarehouseList`
is being assigned asynchronously but the formControlName `fromWarehouseId` is being assigned
immediately and as a result user can't see dropdown value correctly. What I have tried so far ;

1. Tried to use observable to notify parent component when `p-dropdown` is rendered. But couldn't manage
2. Tried to use `ngAfterViewInit`   in parent component but didn't change anything.
3. Tried to use `settimeOut` but ı don't think it's right thing to do.

Comment: After the values have been set, use `setValue` to set the formcontrol value.

Comment: You can also display the dropdown conditionally, so you can make sure it is only rendered when all the data needed to do so is available.

Comment: I already tried but it's not working. Because I  fetching values and options from database seperately. Even if I use `setValue` after options has been set, I can't guarantee value has been fetched from database.

Comment: I tried it. But this time it's making other parts broken. For example for this  I added `*ngIf="fromWarehouseList.lengtn>0` but I'm using same form to display and create data. So when user tries to create a data using this form, it's not being rendered .Becasuse list is empty when user tries to create a form @Allan Juan

Comment: If it depends on 2 values being fetched, use `forkJoin` to run the both async request at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you in comment say that both values, `fromWarehouseList` and the formcontrol value is being fetched async, then use `forkJoin` (using observables) to run the request at the same time, so you then also know when you have both values. So, something like this:

```ts
forkJoin([this.getDataForTable(), this.getValueForFormControl()])
 .subscribe([tableData, formControlData] => {
   this.fromWarehouseList = tableData;
   this.myForm.get('fromWarehouseId').setValue(formControlData);
 })
```

Of course, type your data, here I have not, as I don't know how your data looks like, or what your types are ;)